# Desktop friendly multiple dropdownlist while keeping smartphones default style

Tags: html, css, smartphone, dropdownbox

I have a basic HTML dropdownlist that's basically this:

```
<select id="drpTest" name="drpTest" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

It does what it should do, but it isn't exactly user friendly, since you have to hold down control while pressing to select several options.
However on smarthphones like Android they work great like this [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3XAu.png) but obviously with checkboxes(this image shows the normal dropdownlist not multiple but they're basically the same)

But the issue are the desktops. I've tried to use various plugins and so on like http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/#multiple-select

And they work great on desktops, but on smartphones they no longer use the default Android dropdownlist, rather they use the new desktop one which doesn't work that great for smartphones.

Is there a good way to design the multiple dropdownlist to make it more desktop friendly while keeping it "normal" in the way that Android will display it as normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8W2Z6/)

One option would be to use [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) to show a normal select box for android/mobile devices, then a replaced select box for desktop machines

HTML

```
<select id='mobile'>
    <option>Mobile Select Box</option>
</select>
<select id='desktop'>
    <option>Desktop Select Box</option>
</select>
```

CSS

```
#mobile {
    display:none;
}
#desktop {
    display:block;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    #desktop {
        display:none;
    }
    #mobile {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

Comment: This could work even though it is a bit annoying to have two seperate lists. But is this really the best way to do it? incase we have a desktop user sitting on a small monitor or a larger mobile device like a tablet.

Comment: You can always refine the nature of the query to more accurately filter devices: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: I'm using one of the bootstraps so I have available those various classes to display or hide for phone/tablet/desktop but they're still only based on resolution so it isn't impossible for a desktop user to have a really small monitor or vice versa. And having to deal with two lists when posting the form is also annoying. But this will do and is probably the best out there.