# Check if select element opens within the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I need to know if the < select > element opens within the page or in a external box.
Take this image as example:  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/Art/custom_select_implement.jpg

Is it possible to know what will happen when the user clicks or touchs the select element?
If it will behave like image A or image B.

thanks,
Joe

Comment: I believe the only way to know this is to know which browsers (such as mobile safari) open selects in this way and then detect the browser via `navigator.userAgent` and react accordingly.

Comment: This can't be detected reliably because the text box on native devices is handled by the OS. You'd have to approach it the way @Mike describes

Answer (score 0):

I believe this answer will solve your problem.  It recommends using Media queries through css to check the environment and act accordingly.

[Desktop friendly multiple dropdownlist while keeping smartphones default style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23077889/desktop-friendly-multiple-dropdownlist-while-keeping-smartphones-default-style)

Comment: the problem is that I just tested a galaxy tablet and it opened like a desktop for select-one and opened in a "lightbox" when the select was a multiple. I don't know if checking for sizes is the best way

Comment: I think you're running into one of the main problems developing for mobile, which is that there are so many fragmented versions of Android these days, it's almost impossible to cover all bases. If you go with what Mike suggests above, you can get specific versions and directly address those, but there's little chance of supporting them all, especially when we're seeing a new version of the OS at least once a year, and new flavors more often than that (Firefox OS, Kindle Fire Phone, etc).